# Downloading pdf files with wget. (characters after file extension?)

Tags: shell, pdf, url, web, wget

I'm trying to dowload recursively all .pdf files from a webpage.

The files URL have this format:

```
"http://example.com/fileexample.pdf?id=****"
```

I'm using these parameters:

```
wget -r -l1 -A.pdf http://example.com
```

wget is rejecting all the files when saving. Getting this error when using --debug:

```
Removing file due to recursive rejection criteria in recursive_retrieve()
```

I think that's happening because of this "?id=****" after the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But did you try `-A "*.pdf*"` ? Regarding the wget docs, this should work out.